# SQL query not generating proper results

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got 4 tables:

1. Customers with columns - username, pass, name, etc
2. Books with columns - id, title, author, etc
3. order_details with columns - id_order, id(books id), etc
4. user_order with columns - id_order, username, pass, email, etc

And I want to print out the table with columns order_date, books title, books price, and books quantity which is depicting order history for a particular user in last 3 months

I'm using the following SQL query:

```
SELECT user_order.Order_Date, books.title, books.Price, Order_Details.Quantity
from Customers INNER JOIN user_order ON Customers.username = user_order.username
INNER JOIN Order_Details ON Order_Details.ID_Order = user_order.ID_Order
INNER JOIN books ON books.id = order_Details.ID
AND Customers.username = '".$username."' 
where user_order.ORDER_DATE < ADD_MONTHS(user_order.ORDER_DATE, 3)
```

but it is giving me more rows than expected and with quantity exceeding than desired output.

Can someone please help me in correcting the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your `ADD_MONTHS` command, you are getting a date 3 months in the future. Therefore by saying `ORDER_DATE < 3MonthsInFuture`, you are asking for all existing order dates.

Comment: Yes that was one of the problem, there was also some redundant data in tables which was causing this problem. Thanks so much for the help

Comment: You are very welcome.
If you are satisfied with my answer, please mark it as "accepted" so that the question can be closed.